# How To Call asynchronous system Activity few times sequentially

Tags: android, asynchronous, synchronous

I have two Activity, for example :

1. myMainActivity
2. systemActivity - system asynchronous activity

Call stack like this:

myMainActivity → onClick -> start systemActivity

I need to for a single event onClick  starts systemActivity a few times sequentially, once after the other,- starting one instance systemActivity after the previous systemActivity complete.

Need call stack like this:

1. myMainActivity:  onClick -> start systemActivity
2. systemActivity: work and finish
3. myMainActivity: wait and start again systemActivity
4. systemActivity: work and finish
5. ...and so on…
6. myMainActivity:  onClick -> stop start systemActivity

**Question:**

A problem is that the systemActivity is **system** activity (I can not change its behavior) and operates asynchronously.

I.e. I can NOT do this: 
myMainActivity-> call systemActivity -> wait systemActivity -> and repeat.

In other words, I need to switch from a asynchronous execution to synchronous.

With the help of what Android technology can solve this problem ?

I need you to ask me the direction of my actions, i.e. a general algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I used BroadcastReceiver mechanism.